# How to make Firefox forget ban on website (Youtube)?

Tags: firefox

A desktop computer is moved from location where Youtube (and many other sites) was banned at router to the location where it's allowed.

In new profile, it loads OK, but i need to fix it in old profile.

It shows white screen with favicon, even in Privacy mode. 
Network debugger shows loading files - css, js, previews.

Computer runs Ubuntu 14.04, is under full control of user, no interference from network/place owners and no any "legal malware" to restrict access.

Find in history and "Forget website" is already tried, as well as clearing cache, cookies etc.

Firefox is latest version, regulary updated with all applications.
SQLite databases are maintained by script manually run time to time, no error messages.

Answer (score 1):

In the first place, I was probably wrongly assuming what the root of problem is old fake data returned by router in order to enforce ban, it may be just a malfunction or extensions clash.

I performed https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings and the problem is solved.